# How to print array with any number of dimensions

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, printing

In c# there is no way to print *arrays* directly from `Console.WriteLine`,
so how can I print an arrays with *any number of dimensions*?

Example:

```
int[,] arr = {{2,1}, {5,9}, {3,4}}
```

The Output:

```
[[2, 1], [5, 9], [3, 4]]
```

I know that I can print one dimension array with `String.Join(", ", arr);` or Multi Dimensions using nested `for` loops but this works if I *know the number of dimensions* and I want to print *any datatype* of an array of *arbitrary dimension*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# System.Array How to Count or Find How Many Dimensions It Has?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033641/c-sharp-system-array-how-to-count-or-find-how-many-dimensions-it-has)

Comment: yes, It is a part of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `array` is of *arbitrary* `Rank` you can use [Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-7.0) class to represent such an array (of arbitrary type and arbitrary dimensions) and *recursion* to process, e.g.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

...

private static string Print(Array array, IEnumerable<int> dims) {
  int count = dims.Count();

  return (count == array.Rank) 
    ? array.GetValue(dims.ToArray())?.ToString() ?? "null"
    : "[" + string.Join(", ", Enumerable
        .Range(0, array.GetLength(count))
        .Select(i => Print(array, dims.Append(i)))) + "]";
}

public static string Print(Array array) => array is null 
  ? "null" 
  : Print(array, Array.Empty<int>());
```

Demo:

```
int[,] arr = {{2,1}, {5,9}, {3,4}};

Console.Write(Print(arr));
```

Output:

```
[[2, 1], [5, 9], [3, 4]]
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VYbw3Y)